# How I can replace text of bookmark when bookmark is many paragraphs (lines) with openxml and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml, bookmarks

I tried to replace the text of a bookmark using **openxml**. It works just for the first line of each paragraph and for single lines.

my code :

```
foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
{
    if (bookMarkStart.Name == "signet")
    {
        OpenXmlElement elem = bookMarkStart.NextSibling();

        while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
        {
            OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
            elem.Remove();
            elem = nextElem;
        }

        bookMarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(new Run(new Text("teeeest")), bookMarkStart);
    }
}
```

Below is the xml file which uses the tools. Here I have two paragraphs but only the first one is replaced and I am usinf the bookmark with `id=0`, the second one is added automaticly

```xml
<w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="0028616D" w:rsidRDefault="005537D9">
      <w:bookmarkStart w:name="signet" w:id="0" />
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Test1</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="005537D9" w:rsidRDefault="005537D9">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Test2</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="1" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="005537D9">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
 </w:body>
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant XML so that we can see all the "parts" (tags) of the bookmark?

Comment: @CindyMeister where can i find the xml file ?

Comment: The Open XML SDK Productivity Tool can give it to you, for example. Really, I'm just interested in the tags involved with the bookmark. A bookmark has a start AND an end tag - you need both to get the entire content, plus what's immediately around them in the hierarchy. Bookmarks can be tricky, which is why content controls are better when working with the Open XML...

Comment: @CindyMeister i added the xml file, could you see now ?

Comment: Someone else can help ?

Comment: A couple of remarks, since it's the end of my day: 1) Notice there are TWO bookmarks. The second starts *and ends* before the first bookmark ends. You need to check the `id` of the bookmark end-point that matches the start. 2) You're using `NextSibling` but note that the bookmark and its siblings are children of `<p>`, so it doesn't go to the second paragraph where the end of the bookmark is. You need to adjust your logic accordingly.

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you for your answer, now you have all the stuff, could you post a code to help me please to reach the second paragraph ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's code that works for *exactly* the XML construction you show: The bookmark starts and ends *within* a paragraph, at the start and end of a paragraph. There are numerous other variations and each must be catered to explicitly.

A bookmark consists of a Start and an End point. You need both in order to get the content.

Since a document can have multiple bookmarks, and bookmarks can overlap, it's necessary to get the `Id` of the bookmark in order to identify which end point matches the starting point. The name is only present in the `BookmarkStart` element. Only the `Id` is used in both start and end elements.

It's necessary to determine where (in what kind of structure) the bookmark start and end points lie as this provides information about what the parent, sibling and child elements can be. For this specific use case, as both bookmark start and end are within paragraphs the parents of both are `Paragraph` elements. The code below determines this by checking the `Parent.LocalName`.

In this case, the parent paragraphs of both start and end points are determined. In order to edit the content of all paragraphs within the bookmark a `List` is created; the parent paragraph of the starting point is added to it. An additional `Paragraph` object is created for checking the next sibling paragraphs and this is checked for the bookmark end point. As long as the bookmark end is not in the object for the next sibling paragraph the `while` loop is executed; the next Sibling is added to the `List`.

Once all the paragraphs up to and including that with the end of the bookmark are in the `List`, the `List` is looped to replace the  text in each paragraph. The first `Run` is copied in order to preserve the basic paragraph formatting. All `Run` and `Text` elements are then removed, the copied `Run` is appended with the new text.

At the end, the bookmark end is set to the end of the last paragraph.

```
    private void btnReplaceBookmarkText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileNameDoc = "path name";
        string bkmName = "signet";
        string bkmID = "";
        string parentTypeStart = "";
        string parentTypeEnd = "";
        using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileNameDoc, true))
        {
            Body body = pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            BookmarkStart bkmStart = body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().Where(bkm => bkm.Name == bkmName).FirstOrDefault();
            bkmID = bkmStart.Id;
            BookmarkEnd bkmEnd = body.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>().Where(bkm => bkm.Id == bkmID).FirstOrDefault();
            parentTypeStart = bkmStart.Parent.LocalName;
            parentTypeEnd = bkmEnd.Parent.LocalName;
            int counter = 0;
            if (parentTypeStart == "p" && parentTypeEnd == "p") 
            { //bookmark starts at a paragraph and ends within a paragraph
                Paragraph bkmParaStart = (Paragraph) bkmStart.Parent;
                Paragraph bkmParaEnd = (Paragraph) bkmEnd.Parent;
                Paragraph bkmParaNext = (Paragraph) bkmParaStart; 
                List<Paragraph> paras = new List<Paragraph>();
                paras.Add(bkmParaStart);

                BookmarkEnd x = bkmParaNext.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>().Where(bkm => bkm.Id == bkmID).FirstOrDefault();
                while (x==null) 
                {
                    Paragraph nextPara = (Paragraph) bkmParaNext.NextSibling();
                    if (nextPara != null)
                    {
                        paras.Add(nextPara);
                        bkmParaNext = (Paragraph)nextPara.Clone();
                        x = bkmParaNext.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>().Where(bkm => bkm.Id == bkmID).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                }
                foreach (Paragraph para in paras)
                {
                    string t = "changed string once more " + counter;
                    Run firstRun = para.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Run newRun = (Run) firstRun.Clone();
                    newRun.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
                    para.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
                    para.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
                    para.AppendChild<Run>(newRun).AppendChild<Text>(new Text(t));
                }
                //After replacing the runs and text the bookmark is at the beginning
                //of the paragraph, we want it at the end
                BookmarkEnd newBkmEnd = new BookmarkEnd() { Id = bkmID };
                Paragraph p = paras.Last<Paragraph>();
                p.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>().Where(bkm => bkm.Id==bkmID).FirstOrDefault().Remove();
                p.Append(newBkmEnd);
            }
        }  
    }
```

Note: 
As I'm more at home in the Word object model than XML it's possible the code could be more optimal, but it worked for me.